# How do you create a new NSWindow using Swift in XCode and add content to it programatically?

Tags: user-interface, swift

I come from a background in Java, and I'm trying out using swift for creating OSX and iOS applications. My current project is essentially a flashcard application, and it needs to be able to create a popup window for text-based user prompts (ie, to ask what the question is for the card, or to add String tags for sorting the flashcards by type). Here is the code that I put together so far:

```
//Pulls up a prompt box to add tags
@IBAction func AddTagButton(sender: AnyObject) {
    //Declare new subwindow
    var win = NSWindow(contentRect: NSMakeRect(100, 100, 400, 150),
        styleMask: 1 | 2 | 4 | 8,
        backing: NSBackingStoreType.Buffered, defer: true);

    win.title = "Tag Adder";
    win.center();

    //Add the window to the main viewer
    window.addChildWindow(win, ordered:NSWindowOrderingMode.Above);

    var controller = NSWindowController(window: win);
    controller.showWindow(self);
}
```

This pulls up a new window with the ability to close, resize, minimize, and so on. I need to add a WrappedTextField to this window programmatically, but I couldn't find any resources on how to do so. In Java, the closest analogy would be something along the lines of

```
JFrame frame = new Jframe();
JLabel label = new JLabel("Sample text");
frame.add(label);                                //How is this done in Swift?
frame.setVisible(true);
```

I wrote the main NSWindow by modifying the .xib in XCode (Xcode 6, Beta version 6), but I can't figure out for the life of me how to use the WYSIWYG editor to make a window appear at the push of a button. The best I could do was to make another NSWindow that was minimized/hidden by default, but would show itself when you pushed the button (which isn't exactly a very good solution). The other feature I found was an NSAlert, but that doesn't have a text field for users to input data. My question is how do you add content to an NSWindow that pops up at the push of a button, either by modifying the above method, or by using the .xib GUI editor that XCode provides?

Answer (score 3):

You should add content to the contentView of NSWindow.

```
let textField =. NSTextView()
textView.stringvalue = "Some string"
textView.frame = CGRectMake(10,20,50,400)
 mywindow.contentView.addSubview(textView)
```

Comment: I think `textView.stringvalue` is suppose to be `textView.stringValue` with a capital `V`.